# Why does "DELETE WHERE (VARCHAR)=0" execute successfully?

Tags: mysql, select

```
DELETE FROM stats WHERE name=0
```

"name" is type VARCHAR(64). The above resulted in all records in the table being deleted, instead of just the 10~ that should have been affected. Only that many were actually equal to "0".

Why did this succeed in such cases as: "Mike"=0

Thankfully this was done on a personal development server and not production! I surely want to avoid this happening in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a string (`VARCHAR`) is compared to a number (0), any digits at the beginning of the string are converted to a number.  If there are no digits (eg, 'Mike'), the numeric value is 0.

```
WHERE 'Mike' = 0 -- succeeds
WHERE 'Mike' = '0' -- fails
```

Coding like that cannot be automatically prevented.  This is part of debugging your application.

Similarly, if you use an `INT` in a string context (eg, `CONCAT()`), the `INT` value will be converted to a string.

Answer (score 0):

This is how mysql (other RDMS do it in a different way) performs implicit string to number conversion .  Using bind variables and proper setters in the applications should prevent such behavior.
For instance,

```
//pseudo-code , depends on the programming language/framework you use
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM stats WHERE name = ?");
st.setString(1,"0"); 
st.executeUpdate();
```